# Avoiding HTTP Overhead with GraphQ

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql

It is my understanding that GraphQL uses the HTTP protocol to receive queries. This is normally fine, but HTTP can introduce a lot of latency if you are issuing a lot of queries rapidly. I there another way to rapidly send queries to GraphQL that avoids this latency? I am thinking along the lines of a TCP connection that is persistent across queries so that it does not need to be re-established every time.

I am aware that I can group queries together in GraphQL, but due to limitations in what I am allowed to change, the queries have to issued separately. I am working in C# .NET Core 2.1